is there any way to add more devices on a single slave? modbus connector iot gateway thingsboard
I am reaching out to request your assistance with an issue I am encountering while configuring a Modbus connection in the ThingsBoard platform.
I am currently working on a project that involves the use of a Modbus gateway, and I am facing difficulties configuring the Modbus connection in ThingsBoard. Specifically, I am trying to set up a single Modbus slave to receive data from multiple different devices. However, according to the ThingsBoard documentation, when configuring a Modbus connection slave, it seems that only a single device can be created.
To provide further clarification, according to the documentation, the JSON configuration for the slave looks something like this:
 { "slaves": [ { "host": "ip", "port": "port", "deviceName": "device_name" } ] }
However, in my scenario, I believe I would need something more like this:
{ "slaves": [ { "host": "ip", "port": "port", "devices": ["list_of_devices"] } ] }
I am looking to understand how I can properly configure the Modbus connection in ThingsBoard to accommodate this setup, where a single slave receives data from multiple distinct devices.
Additionally, I would like to mention that I will be attaching some images illustrating the construction of the slave to provide further context.
I would greatly appreciate your guidance on how to configure this connection properly in the ThingsBoard platform. If there are any tutorials or additional documentation that could assist me with this, I would be very grateful if you could share them with me.
Thank you in advance for your attention and support in this matter.
I tried to use that code with the array of devices but I got an error with the missing "deviceName" that the slave should have
